# Como hacer que el Datagridview inserte todos los valores en sql

Tags: datagridview

```
private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

     try
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                    ////// INSERTA RENGLONES
                    SqlCommand Renglon = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SaInventarioMaisonReng (reng_num, co_art, stock) VALUES (@reng_num, @co_art, @stock)", conn);
                    conn.Open();

                    Renglon.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reng_num", Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["reng_num"].Value));
                    Renglon.Parameters.AddWithValue("@co_art", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["co_art"].Value));
                    Renglon.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stock", Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["stock"].Value));

                    Renglon.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    MessageBox.Show("Renglon de Inventario guardado correctamente");
                    limpiarGrid();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)

        {
            MessageBox.Show("No se pudo guardar renglon Inventario Fisico");
        }

        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Queria consultar esta duda que tengo ya que estoy programando un form con un datagridview y al momento de insertar los datos en la tabla SQL
solo me registra la primera fila y he agregado varias en el datagridview, pero me toma sola la primera. que puedo hacer ?

Estoy utilizando C# y base de datos SQL Server

Comment: Hola amigo, limpiarGrid(); debería estar fuera del  foreach

Comment: @EnigmaLABS Hola, aun no me permite guardar varios registros, coloque limpiarGrid(); fuera como me indico

Comment: Recibe algún error?

Comment: Error no me mostraba, pero ejecute un profile SQL al momento de realizar el insert y detecte que estaba agregando un solo registro por que habia creado mal un FK entre la tabla de encabezado y renglon. De todas maneras muchas gracias por la atencion